# Help in Understanding Emission theory of Empedocles

Tags: physics, optics

Empedocles state that the Eyes have fire in them surrounded by water, by this fire ray of the beam goes from eyes to object, then we see that thing, But Question arises to me, Than why not people able see in dark/night, and how they explain shadow of object and light of sun and star, Empedocles must have given any answer o this problem somewhere, but I am unable to find them? Please help me.

Comment: To avoid duplication of effort by prospective answers: Which of the scholarly works on Empedocles' theory of vision have you consulted so far?

Comment: I am reading "A History of Optics From Greek Antiquity to the Nineteenth Century"
https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/13689362-a-history-of-optics-from-greek-antiquity-to-the-nineteenth-century

Comment: See [Lindberg](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Theories_of_Vision_from_Al_kindi_to_Kepl/-8A_auBvyFoC), page 4-5 and see page 6 for Aristotle's rejection.

Comment: For Aristotle, *Sense and Sensibilia*, 437b11: "If the visual organ were fire, which is the doctrine of Empedocles, a doctrine taught also in the *Timaeus*, and if vision were the result of light issuing from the eye as from a lantern, why should the eye not have had the power of seeing even in the dark?"

Comment: But Empedocles' text is quite obscure, and we cannot imagine that it express a "theory" in the modern sense. Maybe we have to read as a similitude and in fact we see something/sometime in the dark: why so? maybe because the eye is like a torch: it has a sort of "inner fire" that illuminate the surroundings. In any case, it seems to me that Empedocles does not speak of "rays".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much of Empedocles exists in fragments of what he originally wrote, so finding his literal writing on the subject may be difficult.  However, we can infer what he said based on the commentary provided by other writers.

Based on snippets in the below link (keyword search "vision" and "night"), it seems that, while our vision reaches from our eyes and reflects back to them for perception, Empedocles also realized that light of the sun was was needed in order for vision to reflect back to our eyes, otherwise it just passes through the object.

Source: https://history.hanover.edu/texts/presoc/emp.html

PASSAGES FROM ARISTOTLE RELATING TO EMPEDOKLES:

> Empedokles says that the light from the sun first enters the
> intermediate space before it comes to vision or to the earth.

PASSAGES IN DIELS' 'DOXOGRAPHIC GRAECI' RELATING TO EMPEDOKLES:

> And he attempts to describe what vision is; and he says that what is
> in the eye is fire and water, and what surrounds it is earth and air,
> through which light being fine enters, as the light in lanterns. Pores
> of fire and water are set alternately, and the fire-pores recognise
> white objects, the water-pores black objects; for the colours
> harmonise with the pores. And the colours move into vision by means of
> effluences. And they are not composed alike . . . and some of opposite
> elements; for some the fire is within and for others it is on the
> outside, **so some animals see better in the daytime and others at
> night; those that have less fire see better by day, for the light
> inside them is balanced by the light outside them; and those that have
> less water see better at night, for what is lacking is made up for
> them.** And in the opposite case the contrary is true; for those that
> have the more fire are dim-sighted, since the fire increasing plasters
> up and covers the pores of water in the daytime; and for those that
> have water in excess, **the same thing happens at night; for the fire is
> covered up by the water. . . . Until in the case of some the water is
> separated by the outside light, and in the case of others the fire by
> the air; for the cure of each is its opposite.** That which is composed
> of both in equal parts is the best tempered and most excellent vision.
> This, approximately, is what he says concerning vision.